# counting based on conditions of tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to count number of employees on the following dataset

```
for combined in dic.iteritems():
    """prints employees by employer and year"""
    print(combined)


 ('a', {2001: 12, 2001: 13, 2001: 15, 2004: 28, 1999: 12})
    ('c', {2000: 23, 2003: 15, 2004: 7, 2005: 24})
    ('b', {2001: 13, 2002: 13, 2012: 12})
    ('e', {2002: 7, 2004: 30, 2005: 7})
    ('d', {2001: 7, 2002: 28, 2010: 24})
    ('g', {2000: 7, 2009: 7, 2010: 333})
    ('f', {2005: 30, 2006: 7, 1999: 12})


for employer, yearIndividuals in dic.iteritems():
    print(employer)
    """iterate over the dictionary to find the combinations"""
    for year, individuals in yearIndividuals.iteritems():
        #print(employer, individuals, year)
        x=employer, individuals, year
        for grp, elemts in groupby(x, (lambda x: x[1], x[0])):

            print(grp, len(list(elmts)))
```

I want output in the following format:

```
employer, year, employee
a, 2001, 3
a, 2004, 1
a, 1999, 1
c, 2000, 1
c, 2003, 1
c, 2004, 1
c, 2005, 1
```

Here is what I need: I am trying to compute the probabilities of people switching jobs. x might work for firm z in year 1 then switch to firm a in year 2.
I am trying to figure out a way how this transition is happening.
Say the table has three columns- `employer`, `employee` and `year`.
In my above example, letter `a` indicate employer, while digits `12` etc indicate employee.

How to I do this?

Generally my requirement is to match employers to individuals and count

Comment: A prefered programming language?

Comment: @Nikolas python. Actually this part of calculating transition matrix, if you have advise on that as well

Comment: So next time, please tag the language as well. :)) However, I am not a pythonist.

Comment: @Nikolas can u do that in SQL?

Comment: SQL is not appropriate for transformations. I suggest you stick with Python. What does the table look like? What is your input and what exactly do you struggle with? You need to provide important details.

Comment: Here is what I need: I am trying to compute the probabilities of people switching jobs. x might work for firm z in year 1 then switch to firm a in year 2. I am trying to figure out a way how this transition is happening.

Comment: Say the table has three columns- employer, employee and year

Comment: In my above example, letter 'a' indicate employer, while digits '12' etc indicate employee.

Comment: Always edit the question :) The comments will usually disappear. Everyone reads the question first and that's usually all.

Comment: could you have several employees in the same year

Comment: @Serge yes real data will have that scenario. this is just a dummy data

Comment: to find probabity of employee changing job (having more than 2 jobs during live) you need just count the number of all employees and those having more than 1 job. If you need probability of changing job per year first tell us what year means - being hired or working

Comment: the differnce that with multiple employees per year you need different data type, say with employee's list

Comment: generally, I would expect one employer per employee for that year or may be couple of employers. But it could vary. So to your question - year means a person was working (does not really matter if it was being hired or working), I will take both as same.

Comment: but yes an employee could have multiple employer for that year. And an employer could have multiple employee for that year.

Comment: If you see the table I have provided above, employer a has multiple employees for year 2001. While employee 7 has multiple employers over the years.

Comment: @lpt A dictionary can only have unique keys, this... `{2001: 12, 2001: 13, 2001: 15, ...}` is not a valid Python dictionary. Can you update your question with the actual data?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have same key (year) in a dictionary. Yet you can do have a list of employees hired for particular year, e.g. `2001: [12, 13, 15]`. Then listing is simple as

```
for employer in dic:
    for year in dic[employer]:
        for employee in dic[employer][year]:
            print employer, year, employee
```

The simple way to estimate probability of employee switching jobs i.e. having more than two job during recorded period is to divide the number of employees with more than two jobs on number of employees

Comment: While your code may solve the problem, consider adding a short description to help others understand how your code answers the question.

Comment: I waiting topic starter to correct the problem description